# Expose SD card as SD card through USB adapter

Tags: usb, sd-card

How can I get an SD card which is being interfaced with using a USB adapter to appear as an SD card to a computer? This would entail being able to get data about the SD card, such as its CID or CSD, and being able to send MMC/SD commands to it. On Linux, this would mean that its device node name would begin with `mmcblk`. Can this be achieved on the OS side? If not, are there USB adapters that would expose it as an SD card to whatever computer it is plugged knto?

Comment: I'd say the best you can *wish* for is a bridge that maps/translates *certain* non-read/write SCSI commands (e.g. UNMAP) to "equivalent" MMC commands. But in reality, I doubt that any vendor has ever made such kind of bridge. And AFAIK, unlike the case of ATA and NVMe, no SCSI translation standard / reference has ever been proposed for MMC.

Comment: The Linux kernel v6.1.7 has 3 device drivers that seem to support MMC & SD over USB: **rtsx_usb_sdmmc.c**, **vub300.c**, and **ushc.c**. Perhaps these drivers access the SD card information registers as part of ordinary initialization (just like every other MMC/SD driver might do)? Note that MMC and SD are related but actually two distinct, different standards controlled by different committees/organizations. Since they do have some commonalities (e.g. can use the same socket), controllers (and their drivers) have been combined to support both standards.

Comment: Hmm, I thought for some reasons SD/MMC host controller cannot work on USB, but apparently it's really just because of market reasons that they are rare. You'll probably have a hard time finding an adapter that actually uses any of the chips as no one would expect one that requires specific driver (instead of generic driver for USB MSC) to work. Most likely these chips are only found on some (old) laptops and are somewhat slow/archaic. (It might even be comparatively more possible to make one yourself than to find one on the market, since the chips alone are easier to get.)